# Example of a non-abelain finite group $G$ with $G/N$ abelian and infinite group $G$ with $G/N$ finite

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups, infinite-groups

Have not been able to think of a examples with the following properties:

1. Example of a non-abelian finite group $G$ with property that $G/N$ is abelian for every non-trivial normal subgroup $N$ of $G$.
2. Example of an infinite group $G$ with property that $G/N$ is finite for every non-trivial normal subgroup $N$ of $G$.

Also, please explain why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For a nonabelian non-simple example of (2) take SL(3,Z).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: (1) $Q_8, S_3.$ (2) $\mathbb Z.$

Comment: (1) I have never come accross $Q_8$ so dont worry about that one, but thanks for the $S_3$ example, how does $S_3$ have this property? I cant see how this is the case. (2) Totally understand this one, should have thought of that.

Comment: What is the order of $S_3/A_3$?

Comment: @dmdmdmdmdmd: it's two.

Comment: Right.  So what do you know about groups of prime order?

Comment: @Dansmith: $Q_8$ stands for Quaternion group. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group Note that $|S_3| = 6.$ So for any non-trivial normal subgroup $N$ of $S_3,$ the possible orders of $S_3/N$ is $2, 3.$ These are primes and hence cyclic.

Comment: The smallest nonabelian group must satisfy 1, and $S_3$ is it!